# CSS circle border not showing

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get a border around a circle in CSS. I've double-checked to make sure the HTML classes were the same in CSS and tried various combinations of CSS properties. For some reason `border: 4px solid #a569bd;` is filling in the circle instead of becoming a border.

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/prime90/bzc1jt3v/28/)

```css
/* circle icons for legend */

.layer-circle {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.allbrew {
  background-color: black;
}

.brewhunyrds {
  background-color: black;
  border: 4px solid #a569bd;
}
```

```html
<b>Points of Interest</b>
<div class='poi-layer-options'>
  <div class="layer-circle allbrew"></div>
  <a class="layer-text" id="allbrew"><span>Breweries</span><br></a>
  <div class="layer-circle brewhunyrds"></div>
  <a class="layer-text" id="brewhunyrds"><span>Trail Breweries (100 yards)</span><br></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't correspond to what you describe (the jsfiddle does), but what you describe  can happen if `box-sizing: border-box;` applies to that element (maybe caused by an according CSS rule with a `*` selector): Since in this case the given width *includes*  the border and a border of 2 x 50% adds up to 100% (i.e. the full width), the border will completely fill the element.

To avoid that, add `box-sizing: content-box;` to the CSS rules for that element. This will *add*  the border width to the element width / place the border *outside*  the element.

Your fiddle modified accordingly: https://jsfiddle.net/sayxcfrn/

Comment: Or decrease the width of the border to 2px or 3 px

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanth that wouldn't be a real solution, but just a workaround for one particular situation.

Comment: I agree with your answer.But my comment is valid if he wants to keep the size of the circle the same on the screen, but wants to show a border. Any border width less than 50% would work.